# jCarousel and problems displaying items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jcarousel

I'm working on a website that displays galleries, using jCarousel. But no matter what I try, I can't get it to work, and I need to finish this by today. I have a very urgent schedule. My code basically takes image URLs from a database and sends them to AJAX, which passes it to jCarousel which makes the gallery. But there are a few problems:

1. It doesn't display correctly! I can only get the last item pulled from the database, and it displays on the bottom-most row.
2. After the item pulled from the database is displayed, the first time I click on "prev" there's no scroll effect, and the item just disappears! Only if I click on "next" 2-3 times there's a scroll effect and the item remains visible.
3. My items are always displayed at the end of the carousel!

This is urgent.. Please help me fix this.

about.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skins/tango/skin.css" />

    <!--<style type="text/css">

    #wrapper
    {
        width: 700px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #carousel
    {
        margin-top: 120px;
        padding-left: 120px;
    }

    #side
    {
        padding-left: 550px;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 120px;
    }

    #hidden
    {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    </style>-->


    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.easing['BounceEaseOut'] = function(p, t, b, c, d)
{
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75))
    {
        return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    }
    else if (t < (2/2.75))
    {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    }
    else if (t < (2.5/2.75))
    {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    }
    else
    {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
};

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    jQuery('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.next();
        return false;
    });

    jQuery('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.prev();
        return false;
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
        wrap: "first",
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        animation: 1000,
        scroll: 3,
        visible: 3,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null

    });

    jQuery('#mycarousel2').jcarousel({
        easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
        animation: 1000,
        wrap: "first",
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        scroll: 3,
        visible: 3,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null

    });

    jQuery('#mycarousel3').jcarousel({
        easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
        animation: 1000,
        scroll: 3,
        wrap: "first",
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        visible: 3,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null

    });
});

var prevButton = null;

function getObject(b, el)
{
    var currbutton = b;
    var http;
    var url = "about.php";
    var parameters = "d=carousel&cat=" + currbutton;

    try
    {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }

        catch(e)
        {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }

    function getServer() 
    {
        if (http.readyState == 4)
        {
            var i = 0;
            var liArr = http.responseText;
            var built = liArr.split(", ");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var ul1 = document.getElementById("mycarousel");
            var ul2 = document.getElementById("mycarousel2");
            var ul3 = document.getElementById("mycarousel3");

            if (el != prevButton)
            {
                prevButton = el;

                while (ul1.hasChildNodes() ) {ul1.removeChild(ul1.lastChild);}
                while (ul2.hasChildNodes() ) {ul2.removeChild(ul2.lastChild);}
                while (ul3.hasChildNodes() ) {ul3.removeChild(ul3.lastChild);}

            }

            else
                return 0;

            while (i < (built.length) / 3)
            {
                li.innerHTML = built[i];
                ul1.appendChild(li);

                i++;    
            }

            while (i < ((built.length) / 3)*2)
            {
                li.innerHTML = built[i];
                ul2.appendChild(li);

                i++;
            }

            while (i < (built.length))
            {
                li.innerHTML = built[i];
                ul3.appendChild(li);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = getServer;
    http.send(parameters);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="hidden"> </span>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="side">

<form name="cats">

    <input type="button" value="Hats" onclick="getObject('hats', this);"/><br />
    <input type="button" value="Pants" onclick="getObject('pants', this);"/><br />
    <input type="button" value="Shirts" onclick="getObject('shirts', this);"/><br />

</form>

</div>
<div id="carousel">

<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
</ul>
<ul id="mycarousel2" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
</ul>
<ul id="mycarousel3" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
</ul>

<input type="button" id="mycarousel-prev" value="prev" />
<input type="button" id="mycarousel-next" value="next" />

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I commented the CSS because I thought it was giving me trouble, but honestly I have no idea what the hell's going on with jCarousel.

about.php:

```
<?php
echo "<img width='75' height='75' src='http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg' />, hi, hi, hi, hi, hi, hi, hi, hi";

?>
```

Also, even if there are no other items than what is displayed, I'm still able to scroll back, but not forward, assumingly because my item is always placed at the end of the carousel.

I know it looks like a lot of code but it's really not! My formatting takes a lot of lines, the commented CSS takes a lot, and a lot of the code is HTML and jCarousel configuration, and there's also the BounceEasing effect which takes a few lines. There's not much actual code!

So as I said, this is urgent and I need this fixed. But I can't get it to work. Please help me!

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:

I changed the code a bit, but it still does not work. I really need help on this one!!

EDIT:

I added document.createElement("li"); to each while loop. Now all my items are displayed, but they are displayed vertically and not horizontally on each row. Other than that all other problems are the same.

EDIT:

Oh and also, in the row my image displays, only the image is there. Maybe jCarousel doesn't accept img and text, I don't know.

EDIT:

I'm reloading the rows, but it doesn't change anything. Also, I tried adding more images instead of the "hi"s, and it seems that no matter what, I can only get 1 item to display at the first row.

EDIT:

Surrounded the initCallback function with if (state=='init'). It only partially works. Only if a refresh the page a lot of times and spam the prev button I get it to work. There's no scroll effect until about the 10th click. And, first row still contains only 1 item and they're all vertical. I think the first row has only 1 item because I put an image there and the carousel has a fixed height so there's no place for the next item and it just removes it.

EDIT:

It works only if I click the prev button the exact same moment the images load. And I mean, exactly the same moment. What does this mean, in terms of code? How do I fix this?????? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

One thing that is going wrong, I think, is that you create one `li` and change its properties and attach it to different `ul`s. What you should probably do is move `document.createElement('li')` into your loops and create a new one (or clone an old one) every time.

So, basically use this:

```
        while (i < (built.length) / 3)
        {
            li = document.createElement('li');

            li.innerHTML = built[i];
            ul1.appendChild(li);

            i++;    
        }

        while (i < ((built.length) / 3)*2)
        {
            li = document.createElement('li');

            li.innerHTML = built[i];
            ul2.appendChild(li);

            i++;
        }

        while (i < (built.length))
        {
            li = document.createElement('li');

            li.innerHTML = built[i];
            ul3.appendChild(li);

            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved a bit! But now the problem changed: Now it displays the vertically, in each row, and not horizontally. Other than that, everything's the same.

Comment: That sounds more like a css problem :) Is your <img> showing now?

Comment: By the way, jCarousel is a jQuery plugin, right? Wouldn't it be easier to do your ajax calls and your DOM manipulation with jQuery as well?

Comment: Look, here's an example of adding stuff with ajax. Apparently they do want you to stay within their way of doing it, with `carousel.add` and such: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax.html

Comment: Yeah my img is showing. I'll check out what you sent me, thanks. EDIT: I checked it out.. but I have no idea how to adapt it to my code. Could you help me do so please? I also don't know how to use jQuery, I only use it for jCarousel. How do I do my ajax calls and DOM with jQuery?

Comment: Well, there's a lot here: http://docs.jquery.com/. Be sure to check out the "getting started" stuff. I'd recommend learning it as it's easier than javascript in many ways, while in other ways showing you some pretty advanced javascript techniques, if you're interested. In the end, jQuery is just javascript itself. Anyway, documentation of ajax GET calls is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and stuff about DOM manipulation is here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

Comment: ANYWAY, because of your very urgent schedule, we should probably just try to make this work :) Try to use something like `ul1.jcarousel('add', ul1.jcarousel('last') + 1, li)`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, that line replaces all appendChild calls. I tried that right now, but now it doesn't display any item. EDIT: Oh wait I see you changed it I'll retry.. EDIT: still doesn't display anything =/

Comment: Um yes, I changed it... but I think it's not great either. I did see the jCarousel has a reload function , that may be more appropriate to use. So, use your original system of removing and adding `li`'s, then use `ul1.jcarousel('reload')` to rearrange each carousel.

Comment: Ok.. Using it inside the loops makes only the first item appear, and outside the loops makes them all appear but again when I click next the disappear and I have no way of getting them back. Only by refreshing the page.

Comment: There is one more thing: I think the init callback is called every time you init or reset or reload the carousel. So, that may (or may not) create some strange behavior when the events are bound multiple times. So, try: `function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel, state)` and then surrounding your code with `if (state === 'init') {}`.

Comment: Surround the entire initCallback function with if state=='init'? I'll try... edit: Ok.. It rarely works. Only if I spam the "prev" button and refresh at least 5 times then I manage to keep the items. And only after clicking prev like 10 times after refreshing there's a scroll effect. But sometimes it just starts somewhere blank and I have to press "prev" a lot of times before I get to my items. And also, there's still the problem of the items being vertical and the first row having only 1 item.

Comment: I found out how to get it to work manually! It seems that if I catch the prev button before all items load, it works. How do I implement that in code?

Comment: Sounds good, but... catch the prev button? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that.. Well... Forget what I said. It doesn't work that way. It seems that to get it to work I need to randomly click buttons until it works. ~/confused EDIT: Ok I figured it out. It works only if I click the prev button the exact same moment the images finish loading. What does that mean?